# Why my Ajax/php request is executed twice?

Tags: php, ajax

well, i've an like/unlike script.
When i click on like or unlike, the php request is executed twice.
I've tried several things but i don't understand why.

Here my php request.

```
          $query = "SELECT * FROM like_unlike WHERE postid=".$postid." and userid=".$userid;
          $req = $bdd->prepare($query);
          $req->execute();
          $array = $req->fetchALL();
          $count = count($array);

          if($count == 0){
           $insertquery = "INSERT INTO like_unlike(userid,postid,type) 
           values(".$userid.",".$postid.",".$type.")";
           $insertquery = $bdd->prepare($insertquery);
           $insertquery->execute();
```

and here my js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // like and unlike click
    $(".like, .unlike").click(function(){
        var id = this.id;   // Getting Button id
        var split_id = id.split("_");

        var text = split_id[0];
        var postid = split_id[1];  // postid

        // Finding click type
        var type = 0;
        if(text == "like"){
            type = 1;
        }else{
            type = 0;
        }

        // AJAX Request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'likeunlike.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {postid:postid,type:type},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var likes = data['likes'];
                var unlikes = data['unlikes'];
                var difflikes = data['likes'] - data['unlikes'];

                $("#likes_"+postid).text(likes);        // setting likes
                $("#unlikes_"+postid).text(unlikes);  
                $("#difflikes_"+postid).text(difflikes);  // setting unlikes

            }

        });

    });
```

HTML:

```
  <img src="<?= $chemin ?>img/up.png" value="Like" id="<?php echo $id_vote_like; ?>" 
    class="img_vote_up zoom <?= $class_vote_like ?> " style="" />&nbsp;<?= $log_e ?>

   <span id="difflikes_<?php echo $postid; ?>" class="nb_votes"><?php echo $likes_d; ?> 
   </span>

   <?= $log_i ?>

   <img src="<?= $chemin ?>img/down.png" value="Unlike" id="<?php echo 
    $id_vote_unlike; ?>" class="<?= $class_vote_unlike ?> img_vote_down zoom" style="" 
   />&nbsp;<?= $log_e ?>
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the browser development mode network tab of where you are seeing the request 2 times ?

Comment: screenshot https://ibb.co/N1R9Vxf

Comment: Also Can you please provide the HTML used in your code ?

Comment: Not connected to a problem, but still worth to mention:
3 seconds to run script on localhost??? Cmon, this scirpt/db is totally broken. Try to optimise it, add maybe indexes to tables, check all your code and search slow parts etc